# Mongo groupby an object key but preserve the whole object/dict

Tags: mongodb, group-by, pymongo

I am using mongodb and trying to construct a groupby query. A single document looks something like this

```
{
    "_id" : "ca5ff110697611e89c2d9a0012d6e110",
    "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2018-06-06T16:15:55.000Z,
    "CreatedBy" : {
        "Email" : "neo@orangescape.com",
        "Name" : "Neo",
        "_id" : "User001"
    }, 
    },
    "Salary" : 200000
    "Branch" : "C2"
}
```

and my groupby query looks something like this

```
[{'$project': {'Branch': 1, 'CreatedAt.year':{$year:"$CreatedAt"}, 'CreatedBy': 1, 'Salary': 1}}, 
{'$group': {'_id': {'Branch': '$Branch', 
                    'Salary': '$Salary', 
                    'CreatedAt.year': "$CreatedAt.year" , 
                    'CreatedBy': '$CreatedBy._id'}, 
            'Salary': {'$sum': '$Salary'},
            'CreatedBy': "$CreatedBy"
            }}, 
           ]
```

As you see the `CreatedBy` is a nested field and grouping on its `_id` field results in just `_id` field but I want to preserve the `name` and `email` while grouping. Grouping by the whole `CreatedBy` because the user may change their name at some point and the old documents will have old name.

Answer (score 1):

The `$group` stage needs an accumulator operator for each field. To keep the `CreatedBy` field, you can use `$first` for example:

the new query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "Branch": 1,
      "CreatedAt.year": {
        $year: "$CreatedAt"
      },
      "CreatedBy": 1,
      "Salary": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Branch": "$Branch",
        "Salary": "$Salary",
        "CreatedAtYear": "$CreatedAt.year",
        "CreatedBy": "$CreatedBy._id"
      },
      "Salary": {
        "$sum": "$Salary"
      },
      "CreatedBy": {
        "$first": "$CreatedBy"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

result:

```
[
  {
    "CreatedBy": {
      "Email": "neo@orangescape.com",
      "Name": "Neo",
      "_id": "User001"
    },
    "Salary": 200000,
    "_id": {
      "Branch": "C2",
      "CreatedAtYear": 2018,
      "CreatedBy": "User001",
      "Salary": 200000
    }
  }
]
```

you can try it online here: [mongoplayground.net/p/cVNHRD5Rv21](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cVNHRD5Rv21)

Comment: As I mentioned before `first` doesn't make sense unless you have ordered  list of docs. Without that there is a chance I might get the old user name
https://mongoplayground.net/p/XWAXGQPrnmQ - Updated the playground. There is an entry on 2017 with name : Neo1

Comment: @BhavaniRavi why don't you just update all entries in database when a user change it's name ?